# Dirac equation identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I have the homework problem:

> Starting from the Dirac equation, derive the identity $$\bar{u}(p')
>  \gamma^{\mu} u(p) = \frac{1}{2m} \bar{u}(p')(p+p')^{\mu} u(p) +
>  \frac{i}{m}\bar{u}(p') \Sigma^{\mu \nu} q_{\nu} u(p),$$ where $q=p'-p$
> and $\Sigma^{\mu \nu} = \frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}]$.

I am not asking for anybody to solve this problem for me; I would like to solve it myself, but tips on getting started would be appreciated. I am also just confused on the meaning of some of the terms.

I know the Dirac equation for a spinor:
$$(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} -m)u=0$$
And the corresponding equation for the adjoint spinor:
$$\bar{u}(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} -m)=0$$.

So, we have $(p+p')^{\mu}$ appearing in the given identity, but what would $(p')^{\mu}$ be? Is it an operator or a vector? I presume that the notation $\bar{u}(p')$ means an adjoint spinor with momentum $p'.$ Similarly, $u(p)$ is a spinor with momentum value $p.$ I am not sure, in general, what the action of the operator $p_\mu$ is on $u(p).$ Furthermore, because the $(p+p')$ has an upper-index, should I be looking at the Dirac equation in the modified form:
$$(\gamma_\mu p^\mu -m)u=0?$$

Comment: Apart from anything other concerns you may have when deriving the Gordon identity, the easiest way to do the derivation is to work backwards, deriving the left-hand-side from the right.

Comment: A straightforward way to show the identity is to start with the $\Sigma$ term and *simplify* it by using the Dirac equation to reduce the number of gamma matrices in it. Approaches starting with the left side require making it more *complicated*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this formula $p^\mu$ and $p'^\mu$ are not operators, they are just components of some four-vectors.

Notice that from the Dirac equation you have $$  m u(p) = \gamma^\nu p_\nu u(p) $$
$$ m \bar u(p') = \bar u(p') \gamma^\nu p'_\nu $$
Therefore
\begin{align} m \bar u(p') \gamma^\mu u(p) &= \frac12 \bar u(p') \gamma^\mu m u(p) + \frac12 m \bar u(p') \gamma^\mu u(p) = \\
&= \frac12 \bar u(p') \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu p_\nu u(p) + \frac12 \bar u(p') \gamma^\nu p'_\nu \gamma^\mu u(p) = \\
&= \frac12 \bar u(p') \big(\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu p_\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu p'_\nu\big) u(p) \end{align}
Now just show that
$$ \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu p_\nu  + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu p'_\nu = (p+p')^\mu{\bf 1} + 2i \Sigma^{\mu\nu}(p'-p)_\nu$$
where ${\bf 1}$ is the identity matrix. You'll need to use the anticommutation relation of $\gamma^\mu$ matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your conceptual questions so that you can try to derive the identity yourself.

> What would $(p')^{\mu}$ be? Is it an operator or a vector?

It's a four-vector.

> I presume that the notation $\bar{u}(p')$ means an adjoint spinor with momentum $p'.$

Yes, but it's a [Dirac adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_adjoint), not a Hermitian adjoint. You can think of $u$ as a column vector and $\bar u$ as a row vector, in "Dirac spinor space", the vector space of all Dirac spinors.

> I am not sure, in general, what the action of the operator $p_\mu$ is on $u(p).$

To get clarity on this, I think it is helpful to write out the Dirac equation

$$(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu} -m)u(p)=0\tag1$$

*explicitly*.

Using a mostly-minus metric, the Dirac representation of the contravariant [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) $\gamma^\mu$, and
$p^\mu=(E,p^x,p^y,p^z)$, you will find that $\gamma_\mu p^\mu$ is the explicit matrix

$$\begin{align}\gamma_\mu p^\mu&=\eta_{\mu\nu}\gamma^\mu p^\nu=\gamma^0 p^0-\gamma^1 p^1-\gamma^2 p^2-\gamma^3 p^3\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
E & 0 & -p^z & -p^x+ip^y \\
0 & E & -p^x-ip^y & p^z \\
p^z & p^x-ip^y & -E & 0 \\
p^x+ip^y & -p^z & 0 & -E
\end{pmatrix}\end{align}\tag2.$$

This matrix operates on the Dirac spinor $u(p)$, which can have "spin up" or "spin down". In the case of "spin up", this spinor has the [explicit form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor)

$$u(p)=\sqrt{\frac{E+m}{2m}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\frac{p^z}{E+m} \\
\frac{p^x+ip^y}{E+m}
\end{pmatrix}.\tag3$$

You can multiply this matrix by this column vector and check that the Dirac equation (1) is satisfied. You’ll need to use $E^2-(p^x)^2-(p^y)^2-(p^z)^2=m^2$. You might also want to write out the "spin down" version of $u(p)$ and check that it also satisfies (1).

The matrix operation here is in spinor space; $p_\mu$ is no longer a differential operator because this version of the Dirac equation is in momentum space, not position space.

In the Gordon identity that you are trying to prove, the $(p+p')^\mu$ can just come out from between the $\bar u$ and the $u$; like the $m$ in the Dirac equation, it is just multiplying the spinor like a number, not like a matrix,  because there is no $\gamma$ matrix inside.

> Should I be looking at the Dirac equation in the modified form:
> $$(\gamma_\mu p^\mu -m)u=0?$$

Possibly. Contractions can be done "up-down" or "down-up", so use whatever works.